# How to merge static and dynamic forms together in php?

Tags: php

The my project has two forms. The first one is a static form that is used to collect user information (Form One inserts data into a table named, master). Second form is a dynamic form which collects additional information such as dependents (Form Two inserts data into a table named, dependents).

formone.php code:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO master (userid,email,name)VALUES('$userid','$email','$name')";
    $result5 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
}
?>
    

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="testme.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="master" id="master" autocomplete="on">
<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" placeholder="userid" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"/><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"/><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

formtwo.php code:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
?>



<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="dependents" id="dependents">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamic_field">
              <tr>
                <td><input name="duserid[]" type="text" value="value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["id"]); ?>""/></td>
                <td><input name="dfid[]" type="text"  placeholder="Enter DFID"/></td>
                <td><input name="gender" type="text" placeholder="Enter Gender" /></td>
                <td><input name="childname[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Child Name"  /></td>
                <td><input name="age[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Age"/></td>
               
               
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></td>  
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 1;

    $("#add").click(function(){
      i++;
      $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">  <td><input type="text" name="duserid[]" value="value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["id"]); ?>""/></td><td><input type="text" name="dfid[]" placeholder="Enter DFID" /></td><td><input type="text" name="gender[]" placeholder="Enter Gender" /></td><td><input type="text" name="childname[]" placeholder="Enter child Name" /></td><td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
      $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
    });

    $("#submit").on('click',function(){
      var formdata = $("#dependents").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url   :"save.php",
        type  :"POST",
        data  :formdata,
        cache :false,
        success:function(result){
          alert(result);
          $("#dependents")[0].reset();
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

save.php code (This is for formtwo.php):

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');

$privateComData = count($_POST["duserid"]);
    
    if ($privateComData > 0) {
        for ($i=0; $i < $privateComData; $i++) { 
        if (trim($_POST['duserid'] != '')) {
            $duserid   = $_POST["duserid"][$i];
            $dfid  = $_POST["dfid"][$i];
            $gender  = $_POST["gender"][$i];
            $childname   = $_POST["childname"][$i];
            $age  = $_POST["age"][$i];
            
            
            $query  = "INSERT INTO dependents (duserid,dfid,gender,childname,age) VALUES ('$duserid','$dfid','$gender','$childname','$age')";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        }
        }
        echo "Data inserted successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Please Enter Info";
    }

?>
```

I want these two forms consolidated, So, they can be put on the same webpage. Basically, I want them to be submitted with one button instead of having two different submit buttons.

Comment: what is stopping you from just putting all the fields into a single form?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: @imposterSyndrome So, it tired it but then I get the following array undefined array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the attached snippets are just for the demo purposes. but, thank you for sharing your concerns, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: @Farhan undefined array what, for where?  what exactly did you try?

Comment: did you merge your forms together, but not the php to handle them?

Comment: @imposterSyndrome  I wasn't sure either. let me share the exact error for your reference.

Comment: @imposterSyndrome I put the php functions of both the forms together but it caused the error. It gave error for the line: $privateComData = count($_POST["duserid"]); undefined array "duserid"

Comment: i think it would be useful if you reduced your code example down, and showed the combined form and the combined php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put all the form inputs inside a single set of `<form>` tags.

```
<form action="testme.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="master" id="my-single-form" autocomplete="on">
<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" placeholder="userid" />....
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamic_field">
              <tr>
                <td><input name="duserid[]" type="text" /></td>....
</form>
```

You've still got multiple forms and submit them separately, so you need to combine them to one and submit them as one

```
submitForms = function(){
    document.forms["my-single-form"].submit();
}
```

`var formdata = $("#my-single-form").serialize();` //etc

Once you've done this implement some checks for your data - e.g. check `$_POST["duserid"]`  and any other required variables are set before you do any inserting.

Then, and with some immediate urgency go and look up prepared statements and implement them

Comment: I put them all inside one form tag. But, then I get the array undefined error.

Comment: @Farhan I've edited my answer to be more explicit

Comment: Thank you. I applied the suggested edits to the code. But, now only the dependent table values are getting submitted not the master table values.

Comment: it's probably this - `isset($_POST['submit'])` - is it set?

Comment: to change the check for something else in the form.  You require all three variables, so i'd probably check them all - something like `isset($_POST['userid'], $_POST['email'],$_POST['name']`) do some experimenting - or add an input called `submit` to your form

Comment: i experimented with it, but, it did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229584/discussion-between-impostersyndrome-and-farhan).